# Short story. Two brothers from another planet travel to Earth. One finds the other was crucified 2000 years earlier

Tags: story-identification, aliens, time-travel

I'm looking for the short story I read many years ago. It was about 2 gifted brothers from another planet. They got separated on the way to Earth.

The second brother went looking for the first brother only to find he was crucified 2000 years earlier.

Comment: Was this a Christian allegory?

Comment: Haw many is "many years ago"? 5? 50?

Comment: This makes me think of the Keir Dullea film "The Next One" - anyone know if it was based on a short story?

Comment: At least 15 years ago, and I don't think it would've been a Christian allegory due to the origin of the brother.